# How do I use an EXCEL cell address in an INDEX and MATCH formula rather than manually typing the cell value in the MATCH part?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel worksheet with numerous columns of data. I'd like to be able to use three of the columns to populate a fourth.

The image below is a cut of the Excel worksheet to show the upper rows of the four columns in my question.

[image: IMG:]

I need to populate column H with data from column Q on the basis of the data in columns G and P. For example, G2 = "Amber Valley". In column P "Amber Valley" is found next to "Midlands" in column Q. So using

```
=INDEX(Q2:Q327,MATCH("Amber Valley", P2:P327,0),1)
```

populates H2 with the correct data "Midlands" and using

```
=INDEX(Q2:Q327,MATCH("Arun",P2:P327,0),1)
```

populates H4 with the correct data "London and the South East". However, I have hundreds of rows and want to use the cell names i.e. G2, G3, G4... instead of manually typing cell content into the MATCH parenthesis like

```
=INDEX(Q2:Q327,MATCH(G2, P2:P327,0),1)
```

But this is returning N/A. I am a beginner, haven't found a suitable solution online (maybe I'm using the wrong search terms?), and don't know how to get any further so any suggestions will be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Why can you drag the formula to fill the other cells?

Comment: `=INDEX(Q2:Q327,MATCH(G2, P2:P327,0),1)` is fine. It's not that you don't know how to do it, you just have an error somewhere. Looking at the screenshot it seems that you have a leading space in the values in [District]. Is that the case? If not, use the 'evaluate formula' button on the 'formulas' tab to step through your formula and see where you're failing. You have the syntax correct. Don't forget to lock your ranges.

Comment: Hi Reddy, do you mean 'why can't I drag the formula'? I have tried that but the main problem is still the same: the formula is only working with text cell content from the 'District' column G typed as "Amber Valley" in the MATCH parenthesis, and not when I try to use the cell name G2. Dragging to copy the formula down the column will onyl work with the cell name in the string - but that give "N/A".

Comment: Alex M - thank you for looking closer that I had, you are right, there IS a leading space and when I edit that out, using the cell name in the formula works. Thank you so much. Rooky mistake, I will make sure I clean my data in OpenRefine. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Katy,, attached screen shot doesn't identifies Rows & Column ,, please [edit] your post and add new screen shot will help us to figure out the issue,,, meanwhile you can use cell reference in place of NAME, as U tried in last formula MATCH(G2,,, .

Comment: Hi Rajesh S, Alex M commented above and found the answer, I need to do some data cleaning and then, as you say, the cell reference will work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is - clean the data before trying to write and use the formula. There is a space in front of data in the cells of the first column. When removed, the normal INDEX and MATCH formulae will work using the cell reference.